# How to catch GPS data of func LocationManager?

Tags: ios, swift, function, class, core-location

i got some problems with this whole UIViewController thing. My thoughts were, that the viewDidLoad() would be something like a main() in other languages, but especially in this case I don't see any functions called in the viewDidLoad() func.

First of all I am totally confused by the var locationManager which is actually a CLLocationManager and a func at the same time. How?

Where do I call the func locationManager? Can I return the locValue.latitude and the locValue.longitude? How do I catch them in the viewDidLoad()? Finally I want to send these two parameters to something, after I pressed a button (see: func SendButtonAction). 
But my problem is, that I don't know how to bring these two guys from the body of func locationManager to an input in  func SendButtonAction.

Appreciate any help :) I guess I need more basic knowledge.

```
import UIKit
import MapKit
import CoreLocation

class GPSNew: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate {


    @IBOutlet weak var mapView: MKMapView!
    @IBOutlet weak var zurueckButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var SendButton: UIButton!


    var locationManager = CLLocationManager()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Ask for Authorisation from the User.
        self.locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()

        // For use in foreground
        self.locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()

        if CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled() {
            locationManager.delegate = self
            locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyNearestTenMeters
            locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
        }

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }




    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        //guard let locValue: CLLocationCoordinate2D = manager.location?.coordinate else { return }
        let locValue: CLLocationCoordinate2D = manager.location!.coordinate
        print("locations = \(locValue.latitude) \(locValue.longitude)")
        let userLocation = locations.last
        let viewRegion = MKCoordinateRegion(center: (userLocation?.coordinate)!, latitudinalMeters: 600, longitudinalMeters: 600)
        self.mapView.setRegion(viewRegion, animated: true)

        //return (locValue.latitude, locValue.longitude)
    }



    @IBAction func SendButtonAction(_ sender: Any) {
        //send the user location to something
        //end updating location
        locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
    }
}
```

Comment: start function names with small letter

Answer (score 0):

Actually the method that gives the location is asynchronous so you can try

```
@IBAction func sendButtonAction(_ sender: Any) { 
    if let loc =  locationManager.location?.coordinate {
       print(loc.latitude, loc.longitude)
       locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From your question it sounds like you're used to procedural programming. In a C command-line utility, for example, you have a `main()` function that gets called at the launch-time. Main calls other functions to do setup, then might have a loop that steps through the work it has to do, and then either loops, waiting for input from the user, or returns if it's a "one-and-done" utility.

Apps for most (all?) GUI-based OS'es don't work that way. They are event-driven, and usually use an object-oriented design. You should read up on event-driven development. Until you study it, you're going to be very confused and won't be able to get off of square one.

Here is a short intro to the concepts, but this is a much deeper topic than we can cover in a simple post:

In an object-oriented,event-driven program, you create objects that have methods (functions) that respond to things that happen. Your program defines a set of starting objects, and then those objects wait for stuff to happen.

The method `viewDidLoad()` is an example of a method that gets called when something happens. It gets called when a view controller's (an object that manages a view) view gets created. It gives you a chance to do one-time setup to get ready for the user to "do stuff." Your viewDidLoad() function does that one-time setup, and then returns.

Control then returns to the system, and your app just waits to get called again.

You might also add methods that respond to the user tapping on buttons, sliding, notifications about updated GPS locations, etc.

The location manager (`CLLocationManager`) is an object that you create when you want to get information about the device's location. You create one, and ask it to notify you about various types of location events. You set up an object to be the location manager's "delegate". This is like giving the location manager a phone number and saying "call this number when the user's location changes."

The location manager calls its delegate when events occur that you told it you care about.

Comment: You guy are a real great teacher. I learned so much from you. The delegate of location manager is the func locationManager ? It must be the same name?

Comment: No, a delegate is an object that gets notified about stuff that happens. (A phone number.) A function is a message that gets sent to the delegate. "Order 12 is ready for pickup." A protocol is the definition of the messages that an object understands. (A contract for the functions and properties that an object must provide if it "conforms to that protocol".) Typically a delegate can be any object that conforms to a specific protocol.

Comment: If you search Xcode docs for CLLocationManager, and click on it's `delegate` property, you should see that the delegate must conform to the `CLLocationManagerDelegate` protocol. If you seach on that, you'll see the things you need to do in order to be a delegate to a location manager.

Comment: Ah ok, but I don't get the difference between the CLLocationManager and the CLLocationManagerDelegate. Is this correct: CLLocationManager is our class and in the protocol CLLocationManagerDelegate which is included in the class CLLocationManager we store all our methods like func locationManager(..)? And than we have to declare our used methods in the code. But where exactly is our func locationManager gets called?